# Each bound to array displays only the first item

Tags: ember.js

I am building an Ember App. I have the following in my template :

```
  {{#if App.selected}}
    <p class="small-desc">{{App.selCount}} product added to list</p>
    {{#each App.selected}}
      {{button-custom action="removeFromList" params=this close="true" class="col-xs-12" text=this}}
    {{/each}}
    {{button-custom action="proceedToDetails" class="col-xs-12" color="red" text="Next"}}
  {{/if}}
```

Here App.selected is an Array `[]`. When a product is selected, it is added to the Array. At the first click, the item(selected) is added and is displayed on the browser. When the next product is clicked, there is no visible change in the browser. But using the console I have checked and ensured that the new product was added to `App.selected`. But Ember displays only the first one.

Due to the very odd nature of this problem and fruitless searches made on Google, I am posting this as a question here.

**Additional info -**

1. NOTE: `App` is not the Ember application. It's just a variable
2. I populate App.selected as :

   ```
   a = App.selected;
   a.push('name');
   Ember.set(App, 'selected', a);
   ```
3. `button-custom` is a component that uses 'text'  as its caption.
4. If I visit the same route without reloading(after selecting more than 1 products), all the items in the array are displayed correctly.
5. Other `{{#each}}`'s that are bound to different arrays on the same page work as they should.
6. I tested the `#each` block on other routes too. Everywhere its the same. I replaced `button-custom` with plain text 'asd' and it exhibits the same behavior. (My intuition tells me I have made some mistake, a very silly one!)
7. The array is declared as :

   ```
   App = {
       selected : null
   }
   ```
8. The controller for this template is an `ObjectController`. Initially, `#each` was bound to `selected` property of the controller. But when that didn't work, I bound it to an array in namespace App. The results were the same, then and now.

**UPDATE**

It seems that each will not *always* iterate over an array. Suppose an `#each` block over variable `Arr`. If `Arr` is `null`, `#each` displays nothing. When you set `Arr` to any array(empty or populated), then Ember renders the contents of `Arr`. But this happens only the first time. The next time you set `Arr` to another array, Ember will not repopulate `#each`, unless you set it to `null`.

Comment: Instead of a.push('name') try a.pushObject('name')

Comment: Can you provide a jsbin with the full code?

Comment: @blessenm I had tried pushObject too. No difference.

Comment: @borisrorsvort There is too much of code. And besides, this is the only code that works erroneously.

Comment: Its strange you use the Global App namespace to handle your collection, I bet you'd have less problems with an ArrayController and a filtered collection:
http://ianpetzer.wordpress.com/2013/06/11/filtering-a-set-of-objects-for-display-in-ember-js/

Comment: As Ember uses conventions I'd advise you to use the mvc patterns :)

Comment: Thanks @borisrorsvort The issue was due to the fact that Ember does not work well with a normal array. I don't know much of MVC but I have tried to stick to as much of it as I know.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ember does not guarantee best results with a JS array. So I had to change my array to `Ember Mutable Array` :

```
    App.Search = {
        selected = Ember.A([]);
    }
```

And then, as @blessenm suggested, add to the array with `pushObject` :

```
    a = App.Search.selected;
    a.pushObject('product');
    Ember.set(App.Search, 'selected', a);
```

To remove from array :

```
    a = App.Search.selected;
    a.removeObject('product');
    Ember.set(App.Search, 'selected', a);
```